# How to change string elements in a list from strings to numpy array names?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a python list, like so:

```
list = [('array_1','array_2'),('array_1','array_3'),('array_2','array_3')]
```

The pairs in the list above are actually named numpy arrays, so I want to remove the quotes around each array name so that I'm left with:

```
list = [(array_1, array_2), (array_1, array_3), (array_2, array_3)]
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can't you just write the list without the quotes? Then the arrays would be in the list.

Comment: The list is automatically generated beforehand (but with a lot more arrays than I listed here)

Answer (score 0):

This will output the numpy array (like `array_1`):

```py
# str will be like : 'array_1' 
globals()[str]
```

or

```py
eval(str)
```

**Note :**

But I recommend to create a dictionary with keys as the strings and values as the corresponding arrays instead of `eval` and `globals()`

like this:

```
dict_ = {'array_1': array_1, 'array_2': array_2, 'array_3': array_3}
```

And use this dictionary wherever you want to access the variable

Answer (score 0):

Now you `lst` will contain actual NumPy arrays instead of just strings.

```
lst = [("array_1", "array_2"), ("array_1", "array_3"), ("array_2", "array_3")]

lst = [(globals()[i], globals()[j]) for i, j in lst]
```

Comment: @SaiSreenivas `eval` make use of `globals` while evaluating expressions and to further add to your suggestion `eval will also fail in case these names are not defined in the global namespace.

Comment: there is no comparison between `eval` and `global` because one is a dictionary and the other evaluates python expressions.